# Passing context value to profile signup template in django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

With django-allauth, I am forcing a new user to fill out additional profile information on signup using a custom ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM.

```
settings.py

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'profiles.signup.ProfileSignupForm'
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False
```

This ProfileSignupForm is then rendered in a modified **allauth/templates/socialaccount/signup.html** template. This modified template renders the logo of the new user's company that is defined in the new user's session (I used an invitation link that first goes to a RedirectView, writes into the session, and then forwards to the new signup).

```
signup.html

<html>
  <body>
    <img src="{{ logo }}" />
    {% crispy form %}
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I pull the company logo from my session and pass it to my template without forking the repository and modifying the SignUp View?

That approach would look like this:

```
class SignupView(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, CloseableSignupMixin, FormView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.company = request.session.get('company')
        ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        context['logo'] = company.logo
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can follow the above mentioned way to Inherit the View and Define custom url for Signup to use your view.

Or

you car **directly access company logo in your template** as:

```
{{ request.session.company.logo }}
```

This can be done because `request` is available as a context variable in Templates if rendered with RequestContext instance.

Comment: Thank you so much, accessing the request directly was exactly what I was looking for. When you guys mention creating a custom url, do you mean setting the socialauth callback url to the new SignupView? Or do you mean setting SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP=True and then creating an adapter to redirect to the custom SignupView if no profile exists for the user?

Comment: We are not talking about providing any settings parameter or so,, Its simple.. In your root urls.py file where you included this line (r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')) to include all-auth's urls.. Define a separate url before the above line whose regex is same as signup url of all-auth e.g. url(r"^signup/$", MySignupView, name="account_signup"),. Now non-social signup will go through this view and you can add any context variable you want in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can inherit SignupView directly in your code instead of forking and modifying the original SignupView.

```
class MySignupView(SignupView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.company = request.session.get('company')
        ...
        return super(MySignupView, self).dispatch(request, *args, *kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MySignupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['logo'] = self.company.logo
        return context
```

Then using `MysignupView.as_view()` in the urls.py.

Comment: It's my impression that the SignupView is called after the socialaccount authentication callback and this url rerouting is handled by the allauth module (instead of a project's urls.py file). This is why you must set the value for ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS to customize the form that SignupView implements. Is there a way to set a hypothetical settings value of ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_VIEW_CLASS to a custom SignupView so that you can customize more than just the form?